# Screen is not getting in edit mode with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

please help me out for below problem of Selenium IDE: Screen is partitioned into two panes: left and right if i am editing any text/type field of right pane then it enables Save and Cancel button at top corners of right pane and left pane get fade out….but when I’m playing the recorded test case back, it gets passed but left pane does not get faded and Save and Cancel button doesn’t appear…only values of text filed gets changed

Comment: How is the page divided? Frames? Divs? Try "select"ing the right frame or "click"ing into the one you want to use.

Comment: page is divided into Divs including tables...selecting a value from link popover has made it

Comment: But what if the right pane would have only text fields and clicking in those field does not take screen into edit mode, is there any other way??

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any HTML for the page it's difficult to help. At a guess I'd say you need the cursor to be actually active within the right pane, and if you're just using a 'type' command this might not do it. Try adding in a 'click' command to click on the editing pane, see if that does the trick

Comment: Clicking in any of the text field is not enabling Save and Cancel button but selecting a value from link popover did the trick....thank you :)

Comment: But what if the right pane would have only text fields and clicking in those field does not take screen into edit mode, is there any other way?